# date format to Mysql database using xampp

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, xampp

i am using jQuery calender to let user insert his/her birthday by thi format 
"2011-OCT-04" but when inserting it into my database i found it by this way "0000-00-00 "

any ideas??!!!

this is screen shot

http://dc426.4shared.com/img/76-nVCx_/s7/0.10678574685889708/date.PNG

Answer (score 0):

Not a xampp issue, try to real [this doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), and also you can try this:

```
 $dates = time();
 $finaldate = date("Y/m/d",$dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to change your date format for mysql like the following :

```
function changeFormatDate($cdate){
list($day,$month,$year)=explode("/",$cdate);
return $year."-".$month."-".$day;
}
```

and then

```
$insertdate = changeFormatDate($postdate);
```